# Is there a place or tool from which I can find or generate genome data for epistasis detection?

Tags: genetics, bioinformatics

I am busy researching a school project for my honors in Electrical Engineering. The project is to create a deep neural network to detect epistasis. I have very little knowledge in the bioinformatics field and while I have managed to pick up most of the theory on epistasis and all of the new terminology, I still lack knowledge of the resources that are available to someone in my position.

I will be needing a large amount of data to train my neural network. I do not mind what form the data is in I just need many examples of epistasis. Where can I find high quality, easily accessible data for this kind? Or alternatively, what tools can I use to generate this kind of data?

Comment: What *specific* kind of data are you looking for? What research have you done so far?

Comment: @MattDMo What I'd like is data that takes the form of a vectors of As, Ts, Cs and Gs, one for each chromosome perhaps. I'm not 100% sure though. I have looked at a tool called GAMETES which generates SNP based models for simulation studies and can also be used to generate data, however the data isn't quite in the form I just described. I have also had a look at PLINK, however, the data it generates is in linkage equilibrium which as I understand it means that it won't be of use for epistasis detection because epistasis occurs when there is linkage disequilibrium.